# How can I control Column Charts with a Slider in Adobe Flash Builder?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I have created Columnchart in Adobe Flash Builder.

Now I want to control that column chart with Slider.
I want to change the column chart according to value of the slider.

How can I achieve this?

Any suggestions are helpful.
Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What Column Chart component are you using ? Would that be the Yahoo! Astra Flash Component ? Which Slider component are you using ? The default one that ships with Flash ? Either way, there should be documentation for the components you're using. You'll need some sort of CHANGE event listener on the slider and you'll update the column you need using the updated slider value.

Comment: @George hi..actually i have created this like dashboard in Adobe flash builder4 only..

Comment: So you're using the Flex framework and the Flash Builder IDE. This question should be re-tagged. Are you using the mx or spark components ?

Comment: @George yeah thats right....i am using mx components...give me some idea how i can achieve it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a listener for the [Change](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/sliderClasses/Slider.html#event%3achange) Event to your Slider component.
Then you update the chart's data provider and re-assign it to the chart.
Here's a modified sample from [Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/tourdeflex/web/).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" verticalAlign="top"
    horizontalAlign="center" backgroundGradientColors="[0x000000,0x323232]" paddingTop="0" viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        private var medalsAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
            { Country: "USA", Gold: 35, Silver:39, Bronze: 29 },
            { Country: "China", Gold: 32, Silver:17, Bronze: 14 },
            { Country: "Russia", Gold: 27, Silver:27, Bronze: 38 } ]);
        //slider change handler
        private function columnSliderChanged(event:Event):void{
            trace(columnSlider.value);//print slider
            medalsAC.getItemAt(1).Gold = columnSlider.value * 10;//assign slider value to Gold for China (item index 1)
            column.dataProvider = medalsAC;//re-assign data provider
        }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Panel title="ColumnChart Control" layout="horizontal" color="0xffffff" borderAlpha="0.15" width="600" height="240"
         paddingTop="10" paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="5" horizontalAlign="center">

         <mx:ColumnChart id="column" height="100%" color="0x323232"
            showDataTips="true" dataProvider="{medalsAC}">

            <mx:horizontalAxis>
                <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="Country"/>
            </mx:horizontalAxis>

            <mx:series>
                <mx:ColumnSeries xField="Country" yField="Gold" displayName="Gold"/>
                <mx:ColumnSeries xField="Country" yField="Silver" displayName="Silver"/>
                <mx:ColumnSeries xField="Country" yField="Bronze" displayName="Bronze"/>
            </mx:series>
        </mx:ColumnChart>

        <mx:Legend dataProvider="{column}" color="0x323232"/>

    </mx:Panel>
    <!-- added a slider here, updates on dragging and has a change event handler -->
    <mx:HSlider id="columnSlider" liveDragging="true" change="columnSliderChanged(event);"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Glad that helps, feel free to close your duplicate question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946497/how-to-control-column-chart-with-hslider) to keep things clean on stackoverflow.